# Norms of elements and their powers

Tags: functional-analysis

For a normed Banach space $X$, The set of bounded linear operators $B(X)$ can also be thought of as a Banach space, with the usual operator norm: $\|T\| = sup_{|x\|=1}\|Tx\|$, where $T$ is inside $B(X)$

What are the cases where the following inequality is valid:

$\|T^n\|^{1/n} \le \|T^m\|^{1/m}$,   with $n,m$ being integers and $n \le m$

I namely wish to understand whether the sequence $T_n = \|T^n\|^{1/n}$ is monotone and increasing.

Comment: What is $x^n$, for $x$ in a [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Definition)?

Comment: Multiplications and powers are not defined for vectors in a general Banach space. Either you thought a specific banach space for which it makes sense or you meant a different operation.

Comment: I suppose you want to consider a Banach algebra?

Comment: I made a mistake by not specifying the space.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been edited but this answer is still valid.

You need something like a Banach algebra to talk about powers of $x$. Even in Banach algebras the inequality is not always valid.  For example in the algbra $B (\mathbb R^{k})$ we can have $T^{m}=0$ without $T^{n}$ being $0$.

Comment: The OP might need to be given something like $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$